# docker-compose cannot attach container to network if full project name given

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running docker desktop(version 4.0.1) in Mac and inside that I am trying my hand in docker compose file for a very simple rest api.

Below is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r ./requirements/requirements.txt

CMD uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 application:app --reload
```

And below is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./server_setup.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    container_name: server
  web_app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    image: mongo-based-fastapi-app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
volumes:
  mongo_data:
```

When I am inside the project directory and run this command : `docker-compose --project-directory . -f ./docker-compose.yml -p test up --build -d web_app` everything works file .

However when I replace the command with the full path to the project like so : `docker-compose --project-directory /Users/subhayanbhattacharya/Studies/HobbyProjects/mongo-book-store-fastapi -f /Users/subhayanbhattacharya/Studies/HobbyProjects/mongo-book-store-fastapi/docker-compose.yml -p /Users/subhayanbhattacharya/Studies/HobbyProjects/mongo-book-store-fastapi up --build -d web_app`, I get the below error message:

```
[+] Building 2.9s (10/10) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                          
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 221B                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 79B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8                                                                                                                 2.4s
 => [auth] tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                      0.2s
 => => transferring context: 265.17kB                                                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.8@sha256:ff437138e8a38edb8f6070c8eefdd570faf1de4dbd0df644c7632160b2b62eb2                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] RUN pip install -r ./requirements/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:5dd081b255c320871c1211985e25f3da664a1be9e5ce4340375213f3a2840ea0                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/mongo-based-fastapi-app                                                                                                                                             0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 1/2
 ⠿ Network /users/subhayanbhattacharya/studies/hobbyprojects/mongo-book-store-fastapi_default  Created                                                                                                 0.1s
 ⠙ Container server                                                                            Creating                                                                                                0.1s
Error response from daemon: container 3157afc2465fe3e8baf6db0aec875155ff62e3714296064794a003076e24aa93 is not connected to the network users/subhayanbhattacharya/studies/hobbyprojects/mongo-book-store-fastapi_default
```

Can someone please tell where I am going wrong ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The [`docker-compose -p` option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--p-to-specify-a-project-name) sets the project _name_, not a path.  By default Compose uses the base name of the project directory, which in turn defaults to the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml` file; you shouldn't need to specify these.  If you do need to override it, use `docker-compose -p some-name` and not a path.

Comment: okay i see, and if it is some name like a path it will fail like it did in my case ?